# Angular application throwing "inline style..." error due to CSP response header configured on server

Tags: angular, webpack, content-security-policy

I am working on an angular application.I am working in angular 8 application with CLI.My application is running on local server without any failure.

On deploying the code to prod server(build using **ng build --prod**) I am getting the below errors , as you can see in below screen shot:
[image]

I know this error is due to CSP response header implemented on server side, which is preventing inline css(you can see the CSP header value in below screen shot set on response header on server):
[image]

I know If I update the CSP header with 'unsafe-inline' for style-src value, above errors will be fixed.

Other workaround(without updating the CSP header) is that not using styleUrls or styles property in component metadata as in below example(styleUrls is commented):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 // styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'] 
})
```

**I just want to know, I have not used any inline CSS then why I am getting these errors?**

Comment: It's possible that the Angular CLI is generating some inline styles in your production build, either directly or after first paint. Are you using any `ngStyle` or perhaps Angular Animations, for example?

Comment: no I am not using ngStyle or angular animation.Yes angular cli add styles under head tag on building.

Comment: looks like this is an issue in angular framework

Comment: on building appliation, inline styles are added under header tag, that is causing the issue

Comment: In that case I think you need to modify your Webpack configuration to build out your app in order to prevent inline styles. I'm not sure if this can be achieved using the Angular CLI or not.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that Angular inject inline styles in the background due to Encapsulation.

That can be causing that issue, despite you are not using inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem when working with Angular and Chrome extensions. In my case I had to set up 2 things for either scripts or styles:

1. **SCRIPTS**: Build the project with subresource-integrity option in order to have all scripts with hash:
   [Angular subresource integrity](https://izifortune.com/angular-subresource-integrity/)

   *ng build --subresource-integrity*
2. **CSS** ( your case ): Disable Inline Critical CSS  in angular.json:
   [Disable Inline Critical CSS](https://0xdbe.github.io/AngularSecurity-DisableInlineCriticalCSS/)

   *"inlineCritical": false*